# If I have to run 500 statistical tests, should I consider each case separately or find the "fittest" one technique?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

Suppose I have to run 500 tests. For example, compare two groups with respect to 500 variables. If for a given variable the two samples are normally distributed, I could do a Student's independent two sample t-test. If it is not, I could do some nonparametric test. Should I consider each test separately? Or just check how normally distributed the samples are in general and then stick to one test. It seems that for correcting false positives (e.g. FDR), I need just the p-values, so it would not matter how testing was actually done. What should I do here? The findings would go into a research paper.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). I am not sure about what you mean but maybe this can help you.